# How to differ Site Page and Wiki Page in MS Graph or SharePoint REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I created a SharePoint Page in SitePages library using the new SharePoint online experience. The page was created and I tried to fetch the page properties using MS Graph endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/site_page.aspx?expand=listItem
```

The response I got:

```
{
    ...
    "name": "site_page.aspx",
    ...
    "file": {
        "mimeType": "application/xml",
        "hashes": {
            "quickXorHash": ""
        }
    },
    ...
    "listItem": {
        ...
        "id": "4",
        ...
        "contentType": {
            "id": "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C411800020BAE24978F3545AFD24007B325ACF9"
        },

        "fields": {
            "FileLeafRef": "site_page.aspx",
            "Title": "site_page",
            "LinkTitle": "site_page",
            "id": "4",
            "ContentType": "Site Page",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added Wiki Page content to this library to support Wiki pages in my site.
I created a new Wiki Page and fetched the page properties again using MS Graph endpoint:

```
    https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{drive-id}/root:/wiki_page.aspx?expand=listItem
```

The response I got:

```
    {
    ...
    "name": "wiki_page.aspx",
    ...
    "file": {
        "mimeType": "application/xml"
    },
    ...
    "listItem": {
        ...
        "id": "5",
        ...
        "contentType": {
            "id": "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C411800020BAE24978F3545AFD24007B325ACF9"
        },

        "fields": {
            "FileLeafRef": "wiki_page.aspx",
            "Title": "wiki_page",
            "LinkTitle": "wiki_page",
            "id": "5",
            "ContentType": "Site Page",
            "WikiField" : "..."
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see both items have the same Content Type. How that is possible?
The only difference being that the wiki_page Item doesn't include 'hashes' property and does include 'WikiField' property (the place where the wiki page content is stored).
Is there another way to distinguish page types?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this endpoint: `GET /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items?expand=fields(select= ContentType)`

My test result:

```
{
            "@odata.etag": "\"b3b04ace-40cd-4847-a3d8-678bc658216d,2\"",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-22T05:34:06Z",
            "eTag": "\"b3b04ace-40cd-4847-a3d8-678bc658216d,2\"",
            "id": "11",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-22T05:34:06Z",
            "webUrl": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/wikipage.aspx",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "amos@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "fc1e9add-6f9c-4b95-83e1-a022441681d7",
                    "displayName": "test"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "amos@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "fc1e9add-6f9c-4b95-83e1-a022441681d7",
                    "displayName": "test"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "id": "79e13173-d5ee-4a17-a081-5c94d148f905",
                "siteId": "xxxx.sharepoint.com,b57886ef-4c2a-4d56-ad29-27266638ac3b,b62d1450-8e6f-4be7-84a3-f6600fd6cc14"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "id": "0x01010800511BB12BD4FB664A89516226DBDDF1FB"
            },
            "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('siteid')/lists('63307f0b-bc1c-4372-bfea-6352ed57a0ff')/items('11')/fields/$entity",
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"b3b04ace-40cd-4847-a3d8-678bc658216d,2\"",
                "ContentType": "Wiki Page"
            }
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "\"70f12845-7646-4b2b-85bd-4a8074c105a0,1\"",
            "createdDateTime": "2020-04-22T05:35:54Z",
            "eTag": "\"70f12845-7646-4b2b-85bd-4a8074c105a0,1\"",
            "id": "12",
            "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-04-22T05:35:54Z",
            "webUrl": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/SitePages/webpartpage.aspx",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "amos@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "fc1e9add-6f9c-4b95-83e1-a022441681d7",
                    "displayName": "test"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "amos@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "id": "fc1e9add-6f9c-4b95-83e1-a022441681d7",
                    "displayName": "test"
                }
            },
            "parentReference": {
                "id": "79e13173-d5ee-4a17-a081-5c94d148f905",
                "siteId": "xxxx.sharepoint.com,b57886ef-4c2a-4d56-ad29-27266638ac3b,b62d1450-8e6f-4be7-84a3-f6600fd6cc14"
            },
            "contentType": {
                "id": "0x0101090100FAC6DAD225005749BE7D6124B50B156E"
            },
            "fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('siteid')/lists('63307f0b-bc1c-4372-bfea-6352ed57a0ff')/items('12')/fields/$entity",
            "fields": {
                "@odata.etag": "\"70f12845-7646-4b2b-85bd-4a8074c105a0,1\"",
                "ContentType": "Web Part Page"
            }
        }
```

You'd better check the type of your page.

**Updatded:**

[image]

```
"fields@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites('siteid')/lists('63307f0b-bc1c-4372-bfea-6352ed57a0ff')/items('13')/fields/$entity"
    "fields": {
                    "@odata.etag": "\"18361706-416b-4a71-8d31-bce87c1a57e4,3\"",
                    "ContentType": "Site Page"
                }
```

Comment: how did you create the wiki page? did you change the content type after the page was created? By default, Site Page content type is set for Wiki and Site Page types

Comment: I did not do anything after I created the pages.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response,  did you create the page with id '13' by clicking 'Wiki Page'?

Comment: No,it is a Site Page.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that when I create a page by clicking 'Wiki Page', the page will have 'Site Page' content type

Comment: And also I would like to mention that I was creating those pages in Communication Site.